# Changing <div></div> to inline-block doesn't work (repl.it included)

Tags: javascript

I can´t seem to be able to change the div element to an inline block. I really need help with this. Here is my repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/AwareContentTechnician

Comment: Sorry, but that repl it full of syntax errors. I also don't see any attempt at setting divs to inline-blocks?

Comment: Your html doesn't contain a `crackerImage` class, and contains duplicate ID's. Also, please include the code in the question itself. Preferably in a [minimal reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

In the example you posted there are no elements with the class "crackerImage", if you want the div to be inline-block you have to add `class="crackerImage"` to the divs you want to be inline-block.

And by the way you should never ever use the same id for more than one element in the html for a lot of reason like google will poorly rank you site, the browser will complain and so on...

this is an example

```
<div class="crackerImage">
    <img data-id="cracker" src="...">
```

And also be careful to put the `=` when you add attributes in html, as you can see they are missing for the `onclick` attributes of the buttons

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. It still doesn´t work though :( I´m sorry if I may seem quite stupid, I´ve just started walking upon this journey of programming

Comment: It works, the divs are inline-block. But is not visible because there are some ```h2``` inside the divs and they are also ```display: block``` by default. You should ```display: inline``` them too. Try inspecting the elements with the [developer tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) of the browser to make some experiments